# How to handle errors with 200 status code in axios?

Tags: axios

My server is return json errors as response of 200 - and I can't change that.

Response for example:

```
{
    errors: [{ code: "unauthorized" }]
}
```

Another response with no error is also return with 200 status:

```
 {
        data: [{ id, name... }]
 }
```

I use `axios` to make http request to get the data.

```
axios({
  url: '//www.mocky.io/v2/5d862b16320000f16d07b36b',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(…).catch(…)
```

Before the any error will gets to the `catch`, I want to handle this error in interceptor. (for example if the error is 401 then redirect)

So I build this interceptor, but I can't able to trigger the error function..

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response: any) => {
    if (response.data.errors) { throw new Error(response.data.errors); return; }
    return response;
}, (error) => {

        console.log('here I want to handle all my errors before it invoke in catch function!'); // <------------

    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

How do I fix that?

[Example code on stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-obpko8?devtoolsheight=60)

The code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.interceptors.response.use((response: any) => {
    console.log({ interceptor: response.data.errors });
    if (response.data.errors) { throw new Error(response.data.errors); return; }
    return response;
}, (error) => {
    console.log('here I want to handle all my errors before it invoke in catch function!');

    return Promise.reject(error);
});

axios({
  url: '//www.mocky.io/v2/5d862b16320000f16d07b36b',
  method: 'GET',
  //responseType: 'json'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log({ response });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log({ error });
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Comment: You need to fix the *server*, errors shouldn't have a 2xx code.

Comment: No I can't fix because I use graphql. and graphql always return errors as 200 status code. this is one reason. and also I'm in big company and this is how thing works in my company.

Comment: Then why are you surprised it "not happends here"? That callback is only invoked for non-2xx errors per https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors.

Comment: I just edited. I think its more clear what I want to achieve.